# AST or bytecode. Which is easier to optimise?

Tags: c, optimization, programming-languages, compiler-optimization, interpreter

So I am making a little toy programming language interpreter, and I would like to try and optimise the code so that the bytecode is slightly smaller. I'm not looking to do very complex optimisations such as loop hoisting, but more simple ones such as constant folding.

My question is, is it better to first generate an AST, optimise that, and then convert to bytecode, or go straight to bytecode, and then try to optimise that?

If anyone has any examples or know of programming languages which do either of these methods it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Details will depend on your language and your compiler implementation, but I'm inclined to guess that some optimizations will be easier to implement on the AST, and others on the bytecode.  Overall, then, that looks like a big, fat "it depends".

Comment: I feel like some things are much easier to do with the tree, yet this requires so much more overhead I'm not sure it's worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both approaches are possible. `tinycc` for example is a C compiler that started as a toy program for the OCCC. It generates executable code directly in one pass, no AST, but still performs on the fly optimisations at the code generator level.

Another example: [wren](http://wren.io/) is an elegant small scripting language with a direct byte code generator without an AST. It performs some optimisations on the byte code, mostly peephole optimisations.

More advanced optimisations are feasible at the byte code level, and I am currently working on a good example that should be published soon, but it seems easier to construct an AST to perform a higher level analysis of the code and generate even better code.

From a theoretical stand point, byte code and AST are 2 representations of the same information, but one seems more practical than the other.

Comment: Lua also does some peephole optimisations without an AST. More interesting (but in a different universe) is LLVM, which has extensive optimisation passes.

Comment: One other thing to consider is whole program optimization such as link time optimization.  With AST the optimizers can identify and factor out duplicate blocks of code (it can be rather slow though)   For example clang will identify functions that have the same effect and replace dups with a jump to a single copy  (annoying if you are testing different optimization methods between compilers)  Theoretically this could be done on any/all chunks of code within functions to separate duplicate code into a single code path (way slower build times though)

Comment: @technosaurus: true, but note that this optimisation can be achieved too at the byte code level by identifying identical sequences of byte code and factoring them. It is just as costly but more extensive as it will also factor identical code produced by different ASTs such as `return a < b ? a : b;` and `if (a < b) return a; else return b;` and `if (a < b) return a; return b;`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19663795/1162141 covers this for assembly and all suggestions call for some form of AST but that's after compilation including register allocation, so I can see how one might be able to do it on byte code in some languages, which may be what John Bollinger was referring to.